# Using TV as a monitor: can't change from 720 x 480 resolution

Tags: 12.04, resolution, hdmi, tv

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my friend's PC and he uses a Technika 22" TV as a monitor.

The screen res is horrible. Went to change it and it says its a MS Telematic 52" and won't let me change the res from 720 x 480.

I should mention I'm plugged in via HDMI not VGA.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. The TV's resolution IS 720 * 480. I guess that because it is just 22'', it is an outdated TV.
2. It says it is a MS Telematic 52" likely because it is a fake. Fake electronics, when connected to **any** computer. reports wrong brands and models.